# Make a div go beneath another one when scrolling

Tags: css

I have the a page that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is that when I scroll the page, only the bottom half should move. I did it but because of the padding it makes it like this:

[image]

This is my css file:

```
.sites-list {
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 400px;
    padding-left: 18rem;
    padding-top: 5%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #396aba;
}
```

When I inspect it in browser and uncheck `top` and `padding-top` it works fine:

[image]

How should I change it to make the white border be there if there is no scrolling but when I scroll to make the text go beneath the blue part as in the last picture?

Comment: I guess `.sites-list` is the content, right? How did you add the blue boxes? Are these div elements? What's the CSS there?

Comment: yes, that's the content. you mean the envelope icon? it is in a different file in javascript

Comment: No the blue borders on top and bottom

Comment: the top half is a different div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how your bars look like in CSS, but here is a working example that uses position: fixed.

```css
.Bar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  z-index: 10;
  
  background: #175f8f;
}

.Bar-top {
  top: 0;
}

.Bar-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

.Content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  padding-top: calc( 20vh + 100px ); /* set to the same height as the bar would be */
  /* If you want to increase the padding and mix relative with absolute dimensions, use calc. Otherwise just add them up for a slightly better performance */
  height: 2000px; /* we cheat a bit so we have something to scroll */
}
```

```html
<div class="Bar Bar-top"></div>
<div class="Content">
  Having your content here.
</div>
<div class="Bar Bar-bottom"></div>
```

Comment: it looks nice but there is no padding before your text. I should have a padding also at the beginning, as you can see in the first picture

Comment: I updated my answer. Increase the padding of the content. If you want to mix relative with absolute dimensions, use `calc`.

Comment: I added something like this and it worked `.all-chapters{
            padding-top: 1.5em;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the blue bar to the following:

```
Position: fixed;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
```

And then set the element which you want the bar
to go over to:

```
z-index: 2;
```

This basically means that the blue bar is 'Fixed' to the top of the browser at all times. The nav element underneath it may require a margin-top of however tall the blue bar is to push it below the blue bar before it has been scrolled.

Comment: I tried it but there is no difference in my oppinion